# Python numpy append ascii data type

Tags: python, numpy, types, ascii

I'm working on a tensorflow project that learns from mp3 files. I have opened the binary data and read it. Then I have converted the binary to ascii. Then I have confirmed that the conversion. But then when I go to append it to a numpy array, it appends blank data.

```
    dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(image_files)),
                     dtype=np.dtype('a16'))
    f = open(image_file, 'rb')
    temp = f.read()
    # sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(image_file)
    # raw_data = sound._data
    audio_array = binascii.b2a_base64(temp)
    # print(audio_array)
    np.append(dataset, audio_array)
    print(dataset)
    print(COUNT)
```

when I `print(audio_array)` I get the following

```
czDne2AxSfpq0DMK9MjrzBw2/F6sMWm/XD47FTN0aXUkq/kIKP2mK3satPUWf9/zTV/t/dTf1Lf//uSBOmNA3pZU6sPOvJ0q0p2PUn2SfFjVAesq8FQrCuo9BUh1f9zRCt//yh7OOuhMogrixdsGrTHd+tGSSaAkPrfqnQ48vFMd6fSBOErLeOipQXe7zkuSt7aFR5J7v3MA3b+gMYpO32b0Kxo/ee/WcN/727XSS/p/1H/8hf5cBCEwWAHBfxdhEKHVomiae73PzIai5...
```

But then when I go to print `dataset` I get the following:

```
['' '' '' ..., '' '' '']
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.append(dataset, audio_array)` returns a new array; it does not modify `dataset`. So change

```
np.append(dataset, audio_array)
```

to

```
dataset = np.append(dataset, audio_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the `help` function of python, it is really helpful.
In this case notice:

```
help(numpy.append)
```

Outputs:
....

```
    Returns
    -------
    append : ndarray
        A copy of `arr` with `values` appended to `axis`.  Note that
        `append` does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and
        filled.  If `axis` is None, `out` is a flattened array.
```

Which means that the passed array isn't modified but copied instead, you must store the return value in dataset:

```
dataset = numpy.append(dataset, audio_array)
```